# Strange setInterval behavior while tab is switched

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have a banner like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/ek658cmz/1/

it's using several intervals to make animation (i can't use jQuery or something like that, in this project), and everything is perfect, before i switch tab. If i switch tab and return back after some seconds my animation isn't working properly, it looks like several animations are trying to be ran at the same time. What is interesting, if i switchback instantly to the banner tab, everything is okay, but more time "out" - more glitches i get.

I've tried to clearInterval on window blur

```
window.addEventListener('blur', function () {
    Banner.stopAnimation();
}, false);
```

like that, also tried to play with animation initiations

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    Banner.init();
}, false);

window.addEventListener('focus', function () {
    Banner.init();
}, false);
```

there was also several atempts to reload page on blur with **location.reload()**, but no success.

What i noticed, when i blur window by just opening another window somewhere, animation is ended normally, and wont start, but when i switch to another time, my animation is like ticking slowly in background for each second

[image]

There is one nuance here also, this banner must be ran in iframe.

Comment: That's the way modern browsers work. When a tab is not active, the browser slows down timers etc.

Comment: Thank you, that explains a lot

Comment: Even if a tab is active, the specification only guarantees a _minimum_ time before triggering the callback - you can't rely on them being run exactly when you ask for them to.

Comment: The time for `setInterval` or `setTimer` is never a guaranteed time, it is always only the minimum time the browser has to wait before the callback is invoked. So for animations you should always check the elapsed time yourself. In addition you might want to look into [`window.requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) which is a better choice for animations in modern browsers.